# Is there a difference between using use and passing the class path to a method?

Tags: php, performance, class, oop, namespaces

In PHP there are two ways to use namespaced classes:

Using an import (`use`) declaration:

```
use The\Class\NameSpace\MyClass;
...
public function myFunction(MyClass $myClass) {
    // Things to do
}
```

Using the fully qualified name every time you use the class:

```
public function myFunction (\The\Class\NameSpace\MyClass $myClass) {
    // Things to do
}
```

In terms of performance, which approach is better?

Comment: I would consider which is more readable than which is quicker.  If you use the same class multiple times - you could (in theory) use different classes - so it depends on your circumstances (IMHO).

Comment: In terms of persormance, Why not benchmark it and tell us

Comment: PHP code is compiled into [opcodes that are understandable to the Zend virtual machine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.php) (VM). Without going into too much details: From the VM's point of view both approaches are equivalent.

Comment: I agree with @KIKOSoftware's comment and that should be turned into an answer. Technically, if you didn't use a `namespace` declaration at the top, and you used the FQN for classes throughout the entire file hundreds or thousands of times, the file would, byte-wise larger, and that could maybe affect performance just from a straight parser, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are functionally equivalent.

There is no performance advantage to either.

The code is compiled ahead of execution, and neither style has an impact or compile or execution time.

Verifying it yourself is trivial writing a very simple benchmark:

```
// Foo.php
namespace Bar;

class Foo
{

    public int $a;
    public function __construct(int $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}
```

```
// test.php
require 'Foo.php';

function footest(Bar\Foo $a): void
{
    $a->a++;
}

$t1  = microtime(true);
$foo = new Bar\Foo(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 200000000; $i++) {
    footest($foo);
}
$t2 = microtime(true);

echo $t2 - $t1;
```

Just run this as is, and again using an import (`use`) statement, and you'll get virtually identical results.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `classpath` to a method that class will only be available inside that method. Using `use` keyword simply allows you to use that class anywhere inside the class you are writing the codes in. So if you are using class `X` multiple times inside another class better to use `use` to remove redundancy in code.

That's the only difference I could find. Other than that functionality remains the same.